# Converting a column from string to to_date populating a different month in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark 1.6.3. When converting a column val1 (of datatype string) to date, the code is populating a different month in the result than what's in the source.

For example, suppose my source is `6/15/2017 18:32`. The code below is producing `15-1-2017` as the result (Note that the month is incorrect).

My code snippet is as below

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_unixtime,unix_timestamp ,to_date
df5 = df.withColumn("val1", to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(("val1"), "mm/dd/yyyy"))))
```

Expected output is `6/15/2017` of date type. Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the incorrect date format. You need to use `MM` for the month (not `mm`).

For example:

```python
df = sqlCtx.createDataFrame([('6/15/2017 18:32',)], ["val1"])
df.printSchema()
#root
# |-- val1: string (nullable = true)
```

As we can see `val1` is a string. We can convert to date using your code with the capital M:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_unixtime, unix_timestamp, to_date
df5 = df.withColumn("val1", to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(("val1"), "MM/dd/yyyy"))))
df5.show()
#+----------+
#|      val1|
#+----------+
#|2017-06-15|
#+----------+
```

The new is a `date` type, which will display as `YYYY-MM-DD`:

```python
df5.printSchema()
#root
# |-- val1: date (nullable = true)
```